# Consider $P(q,t)=\frac{q^{2k+2}-q^{-2k-2}}{q^2-q^{-2}}t^{-2k}-\frac{q^{2k}-q^{-2k}}{q^2-q^{-2}}t^{-2k-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say we have a function of two variables:

$$P(q,t)=\frac{q^{2k+2}-q^{-2k-2}}{q^2-q^{-2}}t^{-2k}-\frac{q^{2k}-q^{-2k}}{q^2-q^{-2}}t^{-2k-2}$$

Prove that:

$$P(1,t)=(k+1)t^{-2k}-kt^{-2k-2}$$

I can't figure out how to do this. I had wolfram do the long division and nothing it gives makes it so I can plug $q=1$ into the equation without a denominator being $0$...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think last relation must be $P(k, t)=$. may be a typo

Answer (score 1):

$ \textbf{Hint:}$
$ a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+...+ab^{k-2}+b^{k-1})$

Use this for $a=q^2$ and $b=q^{-2}$